# Is there a reason to use bases in electrolysis and acids (eg vinegar) for electroplating?

Tags: electrolysis

To me, electrolysis for rust removal and electroplating seem to be the same process, with different metals and goals.

However, in seeing electrolysis and electroplating videos, it seems that electrolysis (for rust removal) uses washing soda, while electroplating uses vinegar.

Similarly, anodizing titanium seems to use a washing/baking soda (base) solution.

I am an EE. It seems to me vinegar would be less conductive. But from a chemistry perspective, what difference does the pH make?

Thank you

Comment: [This](http://www.sapphire-foundation.org/Downloads/STAProjects/2nd%20Sandra%20Goria_report.pdf) may help !